# Как Google удается запомнить данные?

Tags: google-account

1. Зарегистрировал новый аккаунт, зашел, вышел.
2. `Flash`, `Java`, `ActiveX`, `WebRTC` - выключено, включен лишь `JS` так как страница авторизации не загрузиться без него.
3. Почистил систему `CCleaner` и `Wise Care 365`.
4. Браузер очистил полностью еще раз вручную.
5. Сменил IP путем прокси, после прокси еще пробовал VPN.

И вот как, как гуглу удалось после всего этого на странице авторизации подставить мою почту в поле, вроде - `Привет, Мы Вас помним!`?

Comment: Cookies и LocalStorage не забыли почистить? :)

Comment: Попрбуйте удалить печеньки вот как на картинке и попробовать еще раз. https://www.dropbox.com/s/yuf7jubjlcv1wzz/1.bmp?dl=0

Comment: Значит плохо чистил браузер. Просмотрите все опции очистки. Он само-собой запоминает кукии. Отдельно запоминаются поля и пароли  в разных формах - `Пароли и формы` в расширенных настройках. Может это ещё связано с тем, что используете аккаунт хрома `Войдите в аккаунт, чтобы синхронизировать закладки, историю, пароли и другие настройки на всех устройствах. Одновременно будет выполнена авторизация в сервисах Google`. Расширения для браузера?